# Outlook doesn't download all emails, whereas iPhone does

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

When I check my emails on my iPhone, I notice I am seeing emails that are not appearing in Outlook on my computer. This has only happened since I downloaded an Outlook upgrade. I'm afraid of missing important emails. Where are they going?

Answer (score 2):

It could be that your iPhone is deleting the messages off the server before your Outlook client downloads them. Check for a setting related to this. It might be called something like "Leave a copy on the server" or "Delete messages from server after downloading."